# Unexpected result when resizing Vector of Vector of OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 5.4, latest OpenCV. Suppose I have a vector of double

```
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> vecvecdouble;

  vecvecdouble.resize(3, std::vector<double>(3, 0));

  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      if (i == 0){
        vecvecdouble[i][j] = 1;
        vecvecdouble[i][j] = 1;
      }
      if (i == 1){
        vecvecdouble[i][j] = 2;
        vecvecdouble[i][j] = 2;
      }

      if (i == 1 && j == 0){
        std::cout << vecvecdouble[i - 1][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecdouble[i][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecdouble[i + 1][j] << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

It prints

```
1
2
0
```

as expected. However, if I do the same thing with OpenCV `cv::mat`

```
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>> vecvecmat;

  vecvecmat.resize(
      3, std::vector<cv::Mat>(3, cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar(0.0))));

  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      if (i == 0){
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 0) = 1;
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 1) = 1;
      }
      if (i == 1){
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 0) = 2;
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 1) = 2;
      }

      if (i == 1 && j == 0){
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i - 1][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i + 1][j] << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

It prints

```
[2, 2, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which is completely unexpected because I am expecting it to print

```
[1, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, if I don't try to resize the vector in one single line and go through two for loops it actually returns the expected result

```
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>> vecvecmat;

  vecvecmat.resize(3);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      cv::Mat mymat = cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar(0.0));

      vecvecmat[i].push_back(mymat);
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      if (i == 0){
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 0) = 1;
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 1) = 1;
      }
      if (i == 1){
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 0) = 2;
        vecvecmat[i][j].at<double>(0, 1) = 2;
      }

      if (i == 1 && j == 0){
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i - 1][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i][j] << std::endl;
        std::cout << vecvecmat[i + 1][j] << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
```

What is wrong with the line?

```
vecvecmat.resize(3, std::vector<cv::Mat>(3, cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar(0.0))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the copy constructor for `cv::Mat` [says](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a294eaf8a95d2f9c7be19ff594d06278e) (emphasis mine):

> Parameters
>
> `m` Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed matrix. **No data is copied by these constructors.** Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. So, **when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the corresponding elements of `m`**. If you want to have an independent copy of the sub-array, use `Mat::clone()`.

The initial matrix that you construct in your call to `std::vector::resize` is being copied into each element of the vector with this copy constructor*, so they are all pointing to the same data. When you modify one matrix, you modify all of them.

* or maybe with `operator=`, which does the same thing (I'm not sure which, but it doesn't affect the result)

I suggest initializing your vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>> vecvecmat;
vecvecmat.resize(3, std::vector<cv::Mat>());
for(auto& v : vecvecmat)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back(4, 4, CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar(0.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if I do `vecvecmat.resize(3, std::vector<cv::Mat>(3, cv::Mat(4, 4, CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar(0.0)).clone()));` it still yields the wrong result. Is there a way to do it without the for loops?

Comment: All that does is copy the cloned matrix instead of the original matrix, yielding the same problem. I am not aware of any way to use `std::vector::resize` in this situation. There is no way around OpenCV's matrix fake-copying itself like that. You will have to initialize the vector with a loop (easy), use a different math library (might be worth the trouble), or use a different vector implementation that knows to clone OpenCV's matrix (probably not a good idea).